# Series that converges on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples

What is an example of a series that converges only on $[-1,1]$? I am unable to come up with one right now for some reason. Thanks

Comment: You should probably explain in your question in what type of series you are interested. I guess you do not want something like this:
$$f_n(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac1{n^2} & \text{if }x\in[-1,1], \\
    \frac1n & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum \frac{x^n}{n^2}$$

$$\ \ $$

Answer (score 0):

One may consider

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-(1-|x|)n^2-n}
> $$

- If $x \in [-1,1]$ then $$\left| e^{-(1-|x|)n^2-n}\right|\leq e^{-n}$$
  and the initial series converges by comparison.
- If $x \notin [-1,1]$ then, as $n \to \infty$, using
  $-(1-|x|)n^2-n=n((|x|-1)n-1)\to +\infty$, one gets $$ \lim_{n \to   
     +\infty}e^{-(1-|x|)n^2-n}=+\infty \neq0$$ and the initial series diverges trivially.